# App crashes : viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Can someone please tell me why my app crashes if I put something with a viewpager in the same xml file.Thanks.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.g514110.com.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:background="#ddd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>

</LinearLayout>here
```

Comment: Please add the error/crash message you're getting.

Comment: set height other than 0px.. wrap or match.. and remove the wieght.. in this case set height to match_parent

Comment: when I launch. I get "Unfortunatly.App has stopped"

Answer (score 0):

Either add `android:weightSum` to your linaer layout otr give height to your viewpager its missing there

Comment: Still same problem. Once I launch, the app stops.

Comment: com.example.g514110.com.SlidingTabLayout is it correct

Comment: Yes that was it!!Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!! I got the "com.example.g514110.com.SlidingTabLayout" in the xml file wrong actually it's not "com.example.g514110.com.SlidingTabLayout", it's "com.example.g514110.ihmslidingtabs.SlidingTabLayout".Thanks a lot!!