# Open ViewPager In Fragment Make App Crash

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am Working on an Layout that Implements View-pager on the Fragment, the Problem comes as I Implemented the View-pager Layout on the Fragment. As I open the View-pager Main Fragment from Bottom Navigation, the App Got Crash and Show Nothing in It.
Here is the Xml File Main Fragment Where I Implemented View-pager..
This Layout is Implemented after Linear Layout

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tablayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/viewpager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Here is Main Fragment Kotlin File

```
class ViewPagerFragmentMain : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val viewPager: ViewPager = view!!.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    val tabLayout: TabLayout = view!!.findViewById(R.id.tablayout)

    // attach tablayout with viewpager

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    // add your fragments

    // add your fragments
    adapter.addFrag(FragmentViewPagerHistory(), "Tab1")
    adapter.addFrag(FragmentViewPagerHistorySecond(), "Tab2")
    // set adapter on viewpager

    // set adapter on viewpager
    viewPager.adapter = adapter


}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager_main, container, false)
}
```

From Main Activity i am Calling this Method to open Fragment

```
 private fun ShowFragmentViewPager() {
    val newFragment: Fragment = ViewPagerFragmentMain()
    val transaction1: FragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction1.replace(R.id.frameLayout, newFragment);
    transaction1.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction1.commit();
}
```

[image: Image Wher i attached Debugger]

The Debugger Results Are Like this
[image: Result 1]

[image: App Closed]

In Logcat it shows Nothing
[image: Locat]

I am Unable to Understand What I did Wrong...

```
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356867/app-crashes-viewpager][5]
```

After Implemened the Change the Code Look like this
[image: Code after Change]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about [lifecycle of Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating). The code you have written in `onCreate()`, must be in `onViewCreated()`. Or in `onCreateView()`, after setting the view. So basically

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val viewPager: ViewPager = view!!.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    val tabLayout: TabLayout = view!!.findViewById(R.id.tablayout)

    // attach tablayout with viewpager

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    // add your fragments

    // add your fragments
    adapter.addFrag(FragmentViewPagerHistory(), "Tab1")
    adapter.addFrag(FragmentViewPagerHistorySecond(), "Tab2")
    // set adapter on viewpager

    // set adapter on viewpager
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
}
```

The above code is causing the null pointer exception. Because in `onCreate()` view would not be ready and you are trying to access the view.

---

> Update after onCreateView() mess

You need to write code in `onCreateView()` like below

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager_main, container, false)

    val viewPager: ViewPager = rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
    val tabLayout: TabLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout)

    // attach tablayout with viewpager

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    // add your fragments

    // add your fragments
    adapter.addFrag(FragmentViewPagerHistory(), "Tab1")
    adapter.addFrag(FragmentViewPagerHistorySecond(), "Tab2")
    // set adapter on viewpager

    // set adapter on viewpager
    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    
    return rootView
}
```

Comment: I am Using Fragment as It only Contain inflater and container

Comment: I have Implemented this onCreateView but the Issue Remain the Same

Comment: Yes. Does no matter how you are using Fragment, lifecycle remains the same in order.

Comment: Add the code which you have added into onCreateView

Comment: I have Just Updated the Question with the Changes Implemented in it

Comment: I have Done and this Resolved the issue, As I am Inflating after all the things